# preg_match parsing html tags and insert into variable

Tags: php, mysql, curl, preg-match

I have the following tags and I want to extract buying and selling price: 2.9450 and 3.0150

```
<tr bgcolor="#E8EFF3"> 
<td width="25%" align="center" valign="middle" class="tx11"> 
USD</td> 
<td width="8%" class="tx11">RON </td> 
<td align="right" class="tx11"> 
**2.9450**</td> 
<td width="8%" align="left" class="tx11"></td> 
<td align="right" class="tx11"> 
**3.0150**</td> 
<td width="8%" align="left" class="tx11"></td> 
<td align="right" class="tx11"> 
**2.9249**</td> 
</tr>
```

1. can anyone help me with the pattern for the values please?
2. how can I extract the values into variables? 
   thank you

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/159388

Comment: **Don use regex to parse HTML**, use an [html dom parser instead](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all( '/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/s', $str, $matches );
```

$matches[1][0] and $matches[1][1] will contain the two number you want.